# Are these 3 events independent? Not Solved yet. Can anyone help?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, independence

Let us consider 3 events A,B,C such that:

$$P((A \cap B )\cup C)=P(A)*P(B)*P(C)$$

Notice that the second term is a union and not an intersection

Are they independent?

And what if the assumption was: $$P(A \cap( B \cup C))=P(A)*P(B)*P(C)$$?

I know that the independence condition requires us to check whether the probability of the intersection of each pair factorizes plus the probability of the intersection of all of them factorizes as well.

But I do not know how to prove that they are/they are not independent.

**Last Edit: Lozano and antkam's andwers seem conflicting. Can anyone help?**

Thank you

Comment: Yes. They are independent. As far as I am concerned, independence generalizes like this: 
The sets $A_1, ..., A_n$ are called independent *iff*
$$\mathbb{P}( A_1 \cap ... \cap A_n ) = \mathbb{P}(A_1) \cdot ... \cdot \mathbb{P}(A_n)$$

Comment: I am including that in my definition. If you take $n$ abstract sets that satisfy the relation that I wrote down, then they are called independent. For example, for $n=3$, one obtains:
$$\mathbb{P}(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3) = \mathbb{P}(A_1) \cdot \mathbb{P}(A_2) \cdot \mathbb{P}(A_3)$$

Comment: @AndreasMastronikolis  Note, the OP has a union instead of an intersection.  When this question appeared before, the user insisted that the union was correct, but declined to specify the intended meaning.

Comment: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3380347/given-three-events-such-that-p-left-a-cap-b-cup-c-right-p-left-a-right) was the first appearance of this question.  I note that it also just appeared for [a third time](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3381545/impossible-probability-question-about-sets).  It seems very popular.

Comment: @lulu Nice one. I missed that. Isn't a parenthesis required in the expression $$A \cap B \cup C$$ though?

Comment: @AndreasMastronikolis  Yes, that's the problem.  The notation $A\cap B \cup C$ is ambiguous.  Of course, one could simply address both questions, but I think the OP ought to specify which meaning was intended.

Comment: You are right, we do not have $$P(A \cup B \cup C)=P(A)*P(B)*P(C)$$ but $$P(A \cap B \cup C)=P(A)*P(B)*P(C)$$. Moreover, as far as I am concerned strict independence requires also pairwise independence when n=3.

Comment: Only if probability of C is 0.5. In boolean logic it'd be A*B*(1-C).

Comment: I have just edited my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first condition, $P((A \cap B )\cup C)=P(A)*P(B)*P(C)$, is actually very, very restrictive...

- For any $2$ events, $P(X \cup Y) \ge P(X)$
- For any event, $P(Z) \le 1$

So together we have $P((A \cap B) \cup C) \ge P(C) \ge P(A)P(B)P(C)$ for any $3$ events.  If you really have a situation where the first term and the last term are equal, then all three are equal.

$$P(C) = P(A)P(B)P(C) \implies P(A)=P(B)=1 \,\,\,\,\,\,\text{or} \,\,\,\,\,\, P(C)=0$$

- Case 1: $P(A)=P(B)=1$, in this case, $P((A \cap B) \cup C) = 1 = P(C)$ and yes $A,B,C$ are independent.
- Case 2: $P(C) = 0$, in this case, $P((A \cap B) \cup C) = 0$ which further implies $P(A \cap B) = 0$, so you can conclude $A,B$ are exclusive.  (All three can still be independent if $P(A)=P(B)=P(C)=0$.)

---

The second condition, $P(A \cap( B \cup C))=P(A)*P(B)*P(C)$ is much less restrictive than the first, and I won't analyze it in full.  However there are examples either way...

- Example where $A,B,C$ are independent: Just take $P(A)=P(B)=P(C)=0$, or, $P(B)=P(C)=1$.
- Example where $A,B,C$ are dependent: Roll an $8$-sided die with these faces: $A,A,A,ABC,BC,BC,BC,blank$.  Then $LHS=RHS=1/8$.

Also, any example where $A,B,C$ are independent must involve some "degenerate" event ($P=0$ or $1$), because:

$$P(A)P(B)P(C) = P(A \cap (B \cup C)) = P((A\cap B) \cup (A \cap C)) \ge P(A\cap B)$$

so if they are independent we have $P(A)P(B)P(C) \ge P(A)P(B)$ which can happen only if $P(C)=1$ or $P(A)P(B)=0$, i.e. some event must be degenerate.

Comment: I appreciate it. Even if we focus only on the first scenario, I can not reconcile your answer with that of Juan lozano, which does not necessarily points towards independence when P(A)=P(B)=1. Indeed, in his formula if this is the case it turns out that $P(A \cap B \cap C) = P(A \cap B) =1 but this is true only if P(C) is one, otherwise they are not independent.

Comment: @Alchemy, If $P(A)=P(B)=1$ in the first scenario, then $P(C)\geq P(A\cap B)=1$ and hence $P(C)=1$ as well. From this, it is easy to check that this implies the mutual independence of $A, B, C$.

Comment: @SangchulLee - oh, right!  thanks for pointing out that $P(A)=P(B)=1$ implies $P(C)=1$.  i will edit to add this.

Comment: I do not understand what are the events A,B,C in the example where A,B,C are dependent in the second scenario. How do you get lhs=rgs=1/8?

Comment: @Alchemy - Event $A =$ a face with symbol $A$ shows up, and similarly for $B, C$.  So: There are $4$ faces showing $A$, so $P(A)=4/8 = 1/2$.  There are $4$ faces showing $B$, so $P(B)=4/8=1/2$.  There are $4$ faces showing $C$, so $P(C)=4/8=1/2$.  There is only one face satisfying $(A \cap (B\cup C))$, i.e. the face showing $ABC$, so $P(A\cap (B\cup C)) = 1/8$.  If you prefer numeric dicerolls, pretend to roll 1d8 and $A=\{1,2,3,4\}, B=C=\{4,5,6,7\}$.

Answer (score 0):

In boolean logic it'd be  $A*B*(C-1)$ if they're independent. Thus here it is true, only if $P(C)=.5$

Answer (score 0):

We know that 
$P((A \cap B) \cup C) = P(A \cap B) + P(C) - P(A \cap B \cap C) $

Substituting in what we know from the problem we get 
$P(A) \cdot P(B) \cdot P( C) = P(A \cap B) + P(C) - P(A \cap B \cap C) $

Which implies

$- P(A) \cdot P(B) \cdot P( C)   + P(A \cap B) + P(C)  = P(A \cap B \cap C) $

Which shows there can't be three-way independence.

Comment: Thank you. What if $P(A \cup B)=0$ and $P(C)=0$? We could still rule out three way independence, by saying that two disjoint events are never independent, except when they are the null event. Moreover, does independence hold when the three events have all probability 0 (so that they are all null events)?

Comment: The null case is not terribly interesting, because if $P(X) = 0$ then $\forall Y, P(X|Y) = 0$, which means it's independent from all events.

Comment: Thank you. I have the last question: What if $P(A \cap B)=0$ and $P(C)=0$? We could still rule out three way independence, by saying that two disjoint events are never independent, except when they are the null event. Does this work?

Comment: @Alechemy yes, exactly.

Comment: I can not really reconcile your answer with that of @antkam, where it looks like they must be independent because either P(A)=P(B)=1 or P(C)=0. What do you think?

Comment: According to you answer if P(A)=P(B)=1 the events are not necessarily independent. Are they?