# Are $A,B,C$ independent given that $P((A \cap B )\cup C)=P(A)\cdot P(B)\cdot P(C)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability, independence

Can someone help me shading light on this question about independence?The answers look conflicting. [Are these 3 events independent? Not Solved yet. Can anyone help?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3381542/660465)

Comment: Three events are independent if they are pairwise independent, and $\Pr(A\cap B\cap C)= \Pr(A)\Pr(B)\Pr(C).  Some of the answers seem to be ignoring the first requirement.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)#More_than_two_events

Comment: I agree with you, but both Lozano and antkam's reasoning seem good to me. However their conclusions seem conflicting. Which one reasoning is more appropriate to you?

Comment: I couldn't follow Lozano's argument.  (That doesn't mean it's wrong, of course.)  antkham's argument in the first case, which is all I read, seems right to me.

Comment: I can not find any leak in the lozano's reasoning

Comment: Lozano's computations is not wrong. But I am not sure how he made his conclusion from the last equality $$-P(A)P(B)P(C)+P(A\cap B)+P(C)=P(A\cap B\cap C).$$ Indeed, the mutual independence of $A,B,C$ is inconclusive only from this equation, which is also pointed out in antkam's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that

$$P((A\cap B)\cup C) = P(A)P(B)P(C) \tag{*}$$

holds. Then we claim the following.

> **Claim.** $\text{(*)}$ holds if and only if exactly one of the followings is true:
>
> 1. $P(C) = 0$ and $P(A\cap B) = 0$.
> 2. $P(A) = P(B) = P(C) = 1$.

*Proof.* Since 'if' part is easy to check, we only prove 'only if' part. If $P(C) = 0$, then

$$ P(A \cap B) = P((A \cap B) \cup C) \stackrel{\text{(*)}}= P(A)P(B)P(C) = 0. $$

Next, assume that $P(C) > 0$. Using $P((A\cap B) \cup C) \geq P(C)$, we get

$$ 0 \stackrel{\text{(*)}}= P((A \cap B) \cup C) - P(A)P(B)P(C) \geq (1 - P(A)P(B))P(C). $$

Then dividing both sides by $P(C)$ shows that $P(A)P(B) \geq 1$, which forces $P(A) = P(B) = 1$. From this,

$$ P(C) = P(A)P(B)P(C) \stackrel{\text{(*)}}= P((A\cap B)\cup C) \geq P(A\cap B) = 1, $$

which proves the desired claim. $\square$

Comment: Now it is clear. Thank you so much. Just to sum up, if 1. Holds then A,B,C are independent, while if 2. Holds, they are still indep, provided that either  P(A) or  P(B)=0 or both are 0. Right?

Comment: @Alchemy, I guess you accidentally switched the numbering, but otherwise, yes. If $P(A),$ $P(B)$, $P(C)$ are all $1$, then they are mutually independent. If $P(C) = 0$ so that $P(A\cap B) = 0$, then the events are independent exactly when at least one of $A, B$ have zero probability.